# Primsa Nextjs image upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

i have just start leering nextjs

i have nextjs Post route everything is working fine except image is not upload it or showing on post table [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB5Oq.png)

-Below my post Route

so do i need to use cloudinary or local storage to do that and how can i do it because i can not find any video show that

```
import { prisma } from '@/database/prismadb';

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
export const POST = async (request: Request) => {
  const { title, content, tags, authorId } = await request.json();

  try {
    const post = await prisma.post.create({
      data: {
        title,
        content,
        tags,
        authorId,
      },
    });

    return NextResponse.json(post, { status: 201 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(error, { status: 500 });
  }
};
export const GET = async (request: Request) => {
  try {
    const posts = await prisma.post.findMany();

    return NextResponse.json(posts, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(error, { status: 500 });
  }
};
```

- Post component

```
'use client';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import React from 'react';
import { set, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { AiOutlineCloudUpload } from 'react-icons/ai';
interface IFormInput {
  title: string;
  content: string;
  tags: string;
  imgUrl: string;
}
function CreatePost() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const [uploading, setUploading] = React.useState(false);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<IFormInput>();
  const onSubmit = ({ title, content, tags, imgUrl }: IFormInput) => {
    setUploading(true);

    axios
      .post('/api/posts', {
        title,
        content,
        tags,
        authorId: session?.user?.id,
        imgUrl,
      })
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
  return (
    <div className='drawer drawer-end'>
      <input id='my-drawer-4' type='checkbox' className='drawer-toggle' />
      <div className='drawer-content'>
        {/* Page content here */}
        <label htmlFor='my-drawer-4' className='btn btn-accent btn-sm'>
          Create Post
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className='drawer-side'>
        <label htmlFor='my-drawer-4' className='drawer-overlay'></label>
        <form
          className='justify-center h-auto gap-3 p-4 menu w-80 bg-base-200 text-base-content '
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        >
          <h1>
            <span className='text-accent'>Create</span> Post
          </h1>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='title'
            className='rounded-sm input input-accent focus:outline-none'
            {...register('title', { required: true })}
          />
          <textarea
            placeholder='content'
            className='rounded-sm textarea textarea-accent focus:outline-none'
            {...register('content', { required: true })}
          />
          {/* tags */}
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='#tags'
            className='rounded-sm input input-accent focus:outline-none'
            {...register('tags', { required: true })}
          />
          {/* image upload */}

          {/* <input
            type='file'
            id='fileupload'
            className='hidden w-full max-w-xs'
            {...register('imgUrl', { required: true })}
          />
          <label
            htmlFor='fileupload'
            className='flex items-center gap-1 cursor-pointer '
          >
            <span className='text-[10px] tracking-wider text-gray-50'>
              select image
            </span>
            <AiOutlineCloudUpload size={26} className=' text-accent' />
          </label> */}
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='image url'
            className='rounded-sm input input-accent focus:outline-none'
            {...register('imgUrl', { required: true })}
          />

          {errors.imgUrl && (
            <span className='text-xs text-red-500'>image is required</span>
          )}
          <br />

          <button type='submit' className='btn btn-accent btn-sm'>
            Post
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i am expecting image will uploaded and i do get request i can see all post with thier images